# Using VBA to reproduce a tabular pivot

Tags: vba, excel

I am tasked with summarizing some data.  Currently I exceluses a pivot created in VBA and copies it over to a worksheet which is loaded to another system.  Some of our users files are growing in length (450k+ rows excel 2013 32bit) and complexity to the point the code will error out on the pivot process.  I want to use a scripting dictionaries to produce the same output but after finding an example and playing around with it for the last couple of days I need some help.  In the header of the code I have places a sample of the data and the output I am getting versus the output I need which is basically a tabular pivot. The real example is a bit more complex but I think once I see it I can work it out.  I am just missing something in how this is flowing to the worksheet and having a difficult time finding a resource to educate myself on combining the methods below.
Thanks

```
Sub test()

'DATA:
'2005-00000  may 100
'2005-00000  may 100
'2005-00000  may 100
'2005-00000  jun 100
'2005-00000  jun 100
'2005-99999  feb 100
'2005-99999  feb 100
'2005-99999  Nov 100
'2005-22222  apr 100
'2005-22222  apr 100

'Output with Code Below
'            may june   feb Nov apr
'2005-00000  300 200
'2005-99999              200 100
'2005-22222                     200


'Desired Output
'2005-00000  may 300
'2005-00000  jun 200
'2005-99999  feb 200
'2005-99999  Nov 100
'2005-22222  apr 200

Dim strtest As String
Dim a, b(), i As Long, n As Long, t As Long
Dim dict1 As Object, dic2 As Object
Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict1.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict2.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
With Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 3)

    a = .Value
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 1))
    b(1, 1) = Name: n = 1: t = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        If Not dict1.Exists(a(i, 1)) Then
            n = n + 1: b(n, 1) = a(i, 1)
            dict1.Add a(i, 1), n
        End If
        If Not dict2.Exists(a(i, 2)) Then
            t = t + 1: b(1, t) = a(i, 2)
            dict2.Add a(i, 2), t
        End If
        b(dict1(a(i, 1)), dict2(a(i, 2))) = b(dict1(a(i, 1)), dict2(a(i, 2))) + a(i, 3)


    Next
    With .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1)
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Resize(n, t).Value = b
    End With
End With
Set dict1 = Nothing: Set dict2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: 450+ rows? Really? That is causing problems with pivot table generation? PivotTables are very efficient and can summarize much more data than that very fast! Why don't you show us your original code that generates the pivot tables and we can help make that more efficient?

Comment: I left of the k...450,000 + rows

Answer (score 0):

an alternative (to dictionary) solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(, 3).Resize(, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=concatenate(RC[-3], ""§§"", RC[-2])"
    .Value = .Value
    .Copy .Offset(, 1)
    .Offset(, 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    .Offset(, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(, 2), DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="§§"
    .Offset(, 4).Resize(.Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Rows.Count).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C3,C1,RC[-2],C2,RC[-1])"
    .Resize(, 2).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

should there be a lot of rows and it taking too time, you may want to add a `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` statement before the `With...` one and a `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` statement right after the `End With` one